# O(log_2(n)) = O(log_10(n))?

Tags: heap, time-complexity

Is it true to say that an algorithm that is in O(log_2(n)) is also in O(log_10(n))? I would say yes since log_2(n) = log_10(n)/log_10(2) and 1/log_10(2) is a constant.

In that case, if we consider a *d*-ary heap where the heapify operation depends of the height of the tree, why all the documents I have read specify the log radix in the complexity whereas *d* does not depends of the input size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The base of the logarithm can be ignored when talking about asymptotic behavior and the proof is exactly what you have provided.

I believe the papers you mention include the base for better clarity (although apparently it can be confusing too).

Answer (score 0):

When considering [big O  notation ,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

`log₁₀(x) = log₂(x) / log₂(10)` and  `1/log₂(10)` is a constant therefore can be omitted from `asymptotic analysis`.

The base of any logarithm can be changed from `a` to `b`(both `constant wrt. n`)  .

`O(log₁₀(n))` is the same as `O(log₂(n))`, `O(ln(n))`, etc.